# Most efficient way to remove rows for which a subset of the columns exist in another dataframe

Tags: performance, apache-spark, join, optimization, pyspark

I am processing data that has the following details:

- Two tables, `live_table` and `historical_table`
- Both tables have the same columns,`a`, `b`, and `is_live`
- `live_table` is a subset of `historical_table`, with the only difference being that `is_live` is always `true` in `live_table` and is always `false` in `historical_table`

`live_table`:

```
a    b    is_live
1    1    true
2    2    true
```

`historical_table`:

```
a    b    is_live
1    1    false
2    2    false
3    3    false
4    4    false 
5    5    false
```

What I need to do is create a new table, `all_data`, that is a union of the two tables, but have all data that is in both tables to have `is_live` as `true`.

`all_data`:

```
a    b    is_live
1    1    true
2    2    true
3    3    false
4    4    false 
5    5    false
```

The best way I have thought of to do this is with an left anti join followed by a union:

```
historical_table = historical_table.join(live_table, on=[a, b], how='leftanti')
all_data = live_table.union(historical_table)
```

This should work, but `historical_table` is huge with about 21 billion rows and `live_table` has about 50 million rows, so PySpark keeps failing with memory related issues since I think this join is very costly.

Is there any other more efficient way I can achieve this?

Comment: `Is there any other more efficient way I can achieve this?` without join? probably not

Comment: You could have probably used broadcast if the row numbers weren't 50M.

Comment: @venky__ I'm not familair with broadcast joins. Why does having 50 million rows matter? P.S. 50M is the much smaller table. The other table has 21B rows

Comment: Broadacasting copies the table content to each node and if we copy a huge amount it will show outofmemory error https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/broadcast-joins/ https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-joining-in-spark-dcbd33d693c

Comment: try tune parameter, increase parallelism and memory. your join method is correct, and broadcast join cant be used here, 50M is too big to fit in one worker.